# How can i optimize this macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a portfolio report I build from VBA code on monthly and ad-hoc basis. It works fine today, but the underlying VBA is far from optimized. The code sniplet below is repeated 5 times as there are 5 projects in the system now, but it will grow to 50 shortly. Is there anyone that have suggestions as to how I can utilize VBA more elegantly performing the copying to the locations specified in the code (see sniplet below)

```
Sub CreatePortFolio()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    'Clears old data
    Application.Goto Reference:="PFData" 'Named range in the portfolio overview sheet
    Selection.ClearContents
        
'************* Project 1
    If Not Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("BG1").Value = "" Then
        Ark4.Range("B5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("BG1").Value 'Ark4 is the portfolio report and the sheets.count is used to pick the latest import of data - always in the same format
        Ark4.Range("C5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("BF1").Value
        Ark4.Range("D5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("BH1").Value
        Ark4.Range("E5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AU1").Value
        Ark4.Range("F5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AU2").Value
        Ark4.Range("G5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AU3").Value
        Ark4.Range("H5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AV1").Value
        Ark4.Range("I5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AV2").Value
        Ark4.Range("J5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AV3").Value

        Ark4.Range("L4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AP3").Value
        Ark4.Range("L5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AP4").Value
        Ark4.Range("L6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AP5").Value
        Ark4.Range("M4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AQ3").Value
        Ark4.Range("M5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AQ4").Value
        Ark4.Range("M6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AQ5").Value
        Ark4.Range("N4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AR3").Value
        Ark4.Range("N5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AR4").Value
        Ark4.Range("N6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AR5").Value
        Ark4.Range("O4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AS3").Value
        Ark4.Range("O5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AS4").Value
        Ark4.Range("O6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AS5").Value

        Ark4.Range("Q4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AP10").Value
        Ark4.Range("Q5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AP11").Value
        Ark4.Range("Q6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AP12").Value
        Ark4.Range("R4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AQ10").Value
        Ark4.Range("R5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AQ11").Value
        Ark4.Range("R6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AQ12").Value
        Ark4.Range("S4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AR10").Value
        Ark4.Range("S5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AR11").Value
        Ark4.Range("S6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AR12").Value
        Ark4.Range("T4").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AS10").Value
        Ark4.Range("T5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AS11").Value
        Ark4.Range("T6").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AS12").Value

        Ark4.Range("U5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AW4").Value
        Ark4.Range("V5").Value = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("AW3").Value
    End If
    
  
    '******* I Want to avoid copying the above code 50 times *******
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

The Portfolio report look like this:
[image]

The data sheet to build the report from look like this:

[image]

Comment: You should think about moving this question to Code review if this is optimisation matters! Overflow is kinda problem/error solving oriented

Comment: Can you post how the data in the imported sheet is located? is there one imported sheet per project?

Comment: I think you could use nested loops to increment the range values instead of naming each one specifically. You just need to think about how they move relative to eachother. If there are multiple patterns then make a `Sub` for each type of pattern. Then you just pass your starting point in to the subs and call them for each set of data.

Comment: There's really nothing here which tells us how one project differs from the next, so that makes it difficult to generalize an approach which works for any number of projects.

Comment: The data sheet is only one sheet with the exact same format (I have added an example in the org. post) In the example ther is only one projecet. This data is then multplied with the number of projects ie. is repeated with the exact same format but different data obviously. The Data sheet is imported into the workbook and is aut. named with the date and time stamp for the specific time it was imported, Data sheets are kept in the workbook for audit purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim Ark4 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    
    
    
    Set Ark4 = Sheets(1) ' set your sheets
    Set wsData = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    With wsData
        r = .Range("BG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 11
        vDB = .Range("ap1", "bh" & r)
    End With
    For i = 1 To r Step 12
        If vDB(i, 18) <> "" Then
            n = n + 3
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 21, 1 To n)
            
            'Column b ~ j
            vR(1, n - 2) = vDB(i, 18) 'bg1
            vR(2, n - 2) = vDB(i, 17) 'bf1
            vR(3, n - 2) = vDB(i, 19)
            vR(4, n - 2) = vDB(i, 6)
            vR(5, n - 2) = vDB(i + 1, 6)
            vR(6, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 6)
            vR(7, n - 2) = vDB(i, 7)
            vR(8, n - 2) = vDB(i + 1, 7)
            vR(9, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 7)
            
            'Column k ~ o
            vR(10, n - 2) = "Budget"
            vR(10, n - 1) = "Installemnt"
            vR(10, n) = "Deviation"
            
            vR(11, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 1) 'ap3
            vR(11, n - 1) = vDB(i + 3, 1) 'ap4
            vR(11, n) = vDB(i + 4, 1)     'ap5
            vR(12, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 2) 'aq3
            vR(12, n - 1) = vDB(i + 3, 2) 'aq4
            vR(12, n) = vDB(i + 4, 2)     'aq5
            vR(13, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 3) 'ar3
            vR(13, n - 1) = vDB(i + 3, 3) 'ar4
            vR(13, n) = vDB(i + 4, 3)     'ar5
            vR(14, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 4) 'as3
            vR(14, n - 1) = vDB(i + 3, 4) 'as4
            vR(14, n) = vDB(i + 4, 4)     'as5
            
            'Column p ~ z
            vR(15, n - 2) = "Budget"
            vR(15, n - 1) = "Installemnt"
            vR(15, n) = "Deviation"
    
            vR(16, n - 2) = vDB(i + 9, 1) 'ap10
            vR(16, n - 1) = vDB(i + 10, 1) 'ap11
            vR(16, n) = vDB(i + 11, 1)     'ap12
            vR(17, n - 2) = vDB(i + 9, 2) 'aq10
            vR(17, n - 1) = vDB(i + 10, 2) 'aq11
            vR(17, n) = vDB(i + 11, 2)     'aq12
            vR(18, n - 2) = vDB(i + 9, 3) 'ar10
            vR(18, n - 1) = vDB(i + 10, 3) 'ar11
            vR(18, n) = vDB(i + 11, 3)     'ar12
            vR(19, n - 2) = vDB(i + 9, 4) 'as10
            vR(19, n - 1) = vDB(i + 10, 4) 'as11
            vR(19, n) = vDB(i + 11, 4)     'as12
            
            'Column u,v
            vR(20, n - 2) = vDB(i + 3, 8) 'aw4
            vR(21, n - 2) = vDB(i + 2, 8) 'aw3
        End If
    Next i
    
    With Ark4
        .Range("b4").Resize(n, 21) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
End Sub
```

### It is assumed that the data in the data sheet is repeated as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee :-) It took me a while figuring out what you do, but it works perfectly (and fast ...)